# Nikon d3000 and d7100 lenses interchangeable?

Tags: lens

I have been using a Nikon d3000 for about 8 years and recently purchased a d7100. Can anyone tell me if I can auto focus on the d7100 with the d3000 lenses?

Answer (score 4):

Since the D3000 requires lenses which have autofocus motors built into the lens, any lens that will AF on  D3000 will also AF on a D7100.

The D7100 has an AF motor in the camera body that enables it to focus older Nikon AF lenses without an AF motor in the lens. When a lens with an AF motor in the lens is attached to the D7100 it controls the AF via the electrical connection between the camera and lens just as the D3000 does.

Both cameras also have the same sensor size, so any lenses that project an image circle large enough for the D3000 will also project an image circle large enough for the D7100.

Where you might notice some difference is with regards to resolution. The D3000 had a 10 MP sensor. The D7100 has a 24MP sensor. When you pixel peep with images from the D7100 you will be viewing them roughly 2.5X larger than when viewing images from the D3000 on the same monitor. Due to the increased resolution of the D7100, lens performance that was acceptable with the D3000 may not be as acceptable when used on the D7100.

Answer (score 4):

What lens are you talking about? If lens worked OK on d3000, should work OK on d7100.

These cameras has exactly same mount and sensor size, and if anything d7100 is more advanced, can accept wider range of lenses, including everything that works on d3000.

Just make sure switch on the left side of the camera is in AF position for autofocus (there is no such switch on d3000). As well as the switch on the lens should be in AF position (or M/A).